# requestTestAccountTokensWithArraysOfPermissions FBSDK 4.x

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm trying to return a previously created Facebook test user using:

```
let manager = FBSDKTestUsersManager.sharedInstanceForAppID(myAppId, appSecret: myAppSecret)
manager.requestTestAccountTokensWithArraysOfPermissions(nil, createIfNotFound: false)
{
    (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

    if error != nil
    {
      // oops, error
    }
    else
    {
       if let token = objects[0] as? FBSDKAccessToken
       {
         //do something with token
       }
    }
```

But instead of getting an access token, objects[0] contains a NSNull object.  The test users were previously created in code and show up on developers.facebook.com in my app's dashboard

Running the same code with "createIfNotFound: true" works famously, BTW

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Well, I never could get this to work.  I ended up rolling my own, using the code in "FBSDKTestUserManager.m" as a starting point.

```
let graphPath = "\(myAppId)/accounts/test-users"
var params = ["limit": "5"]
let tokenString = "\(myAppId)|\(mAppSecret)"
let request = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: graphPath, parameters: params, tokenString: appAccessToken(), version: nil, HTTPMethod: nil)

request.startWithCompletionHandler
{ (connection: FBSDKGraphRequestConnection!, result: AnyObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

    if let frObjs = dictionary["data"] as? [[String: AnyObject]]
    {
       for frObj in frObjs
       {
           let id = frObj["id"]
           let access_token = frObj["access_token"]
           let login_url = frObj["login_url"]
           // now there's enough info to either login as the test user,
           // or manually create an FBSKDAccessToken
       }
    }
}
```